# Authentication from desktop app

Tags: authentication, windows-services, box-api

I'm building a windows service that would upload files to Box.com under some conditions. 
How can I authenticate without having the user go to a webpage and enter the username and password ?

I can't seem to find the details in the documentation.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, you have two options.

1. You can sign up for the 'instant mode' beta that gets you an authentication token via the /tokens V2 API endpoint, but limits you to accessing a single folder in the user's account.
2. You can use the V1 authentication APIs.  If your app is a company internal app, then we have a V1 authentication API that we can enable for you to do direct logins.   However, direct logins are less secure, and generally discouraged.

Comment: using 1. do I have access to all of the subfolders of the root folder ?

Comment: If you are an application with an instant mode auth token, then you only get access to the app-specific folder.  Your app would be sandboxed in that folder.  So you would not be able to get at any other root-folder level content, nor any other folders off the root folder.   You'd have full reign inside your app folder, but no access outside it.

Comment: How can I enable Instant Mode ?