# Is the "instant mode" way of getting authentication token via the /tokens V2 API endpoint for box.com available?

Tags: box-api

The answer posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486729/1919484 references an 'instant mode' box.com api authentication option that 'gets you an authentication token via the /tokens V2 API endpoint, but limits you to accessing a single folder in the user's account.'

I've googled around for such a thing but I can't find any more info about it. It seems like exactly what I need for an app I'm working on.

Can anyone shed any light on whether such a thing is still in the works, or if it has been canceled or replaced?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instant Mode is a beta feature that we're still testing/iterating on. It's not ready for production applications at this time, but you can email us at API at box.com with your use case so we can let you know when it's ready.